# Ethernet not working on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, ethernet, connection

I have been struggling a lot trying to activate my ethernet connection without success. I am on ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a dell xps8900. I have a dual boot with windows 7 and ethernet is working fine on this one. Here is what I have tried:

1) Verify the ethernet card:

```
>lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 191f (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1901 (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a12f (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a131 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a13a (rev 31)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a110 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a145 (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device a121 (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a170 (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a123 (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15b8 (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 745] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter"
```

2) Then I activated eth0 with ifconfig:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

3) Looking at the error message above, I have modified 70-persistent-net.rules and reboot:

```
mv /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules.old
```

-> reboot

4) I have also looked at the different "eth":

```
ifconfig eth0
eth0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
ifconfig eth1
eth1: error fetching interface information: Device not found
ifconfig eth2
eth2: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

5) Then I tried:

```
sudo dhclient
```

-> reboot

6) Then:

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: b0:c0:90:4f:dc:c2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.16.0-30-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df100000-df103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 31
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df200000-df21ffff
```

Any other things to test? Thank you.

Comment: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products/000005480.html

Comment: I struggled with this problem about two days. Finally I updated my BIOS and it works :))

Answer (score 5):

Follow the steps [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products/000005480.html):

- Download e1000e [here](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=15817)
- Building and installation

  1. Move the base driver tar file to the directory of your choice. For example, use `/home/username/e1000e` or `/usr/local/src/e1000e`
  2. Untar/unzip the archive, where  is the version number for the driver tar file:
  3. Change to the driver src directory, where  is the version number for the driver tar:

     ```
     cd e1000e-<x.x.x>/src/
     tar zxf e1000e-<x.x.x>.tar.gz
     ```
  4. Compile the driver module:

     ```
     make install
     ```

     The binary will be installed as:

     ```
     /lib/modules/<KERNEL VERSION>/kernel/drivers/net/e1000e/e1000e.[k]o
     ```

     The install location listed above is the default location. This may differ for various Linux distributions.
  5. Load the module using either the insmod or modprobe command:

     ```
     modprobe e1000e insmod e1000e
     ```

     Note that for 2.6 kernels the insmod command can be used if the full path to the driver module is specified. For example:

     ```
     insmod /lib/modules/<KERNEL VERSION>/kernel/drivers/net/e1000e/e1000e.ko
     ```

     With 2.6 based kernels also make sure that older e1000e drivers are removed from the kernel, before loading the new module:

     ```
     rmmod e1000e; modprobe e1000e
     ```
  6. Assign an IP address to the interface by entering the following, where  is the interface number:

     ```
     ifconfig eth<x> <IP_address>
     ```
  7. Verify that the interface works. Enter the following, where  is the IP address for another machine on the same subnet as the interface that is being tested:

     ```
     ping <IP_address>
     ```

**Note**

Some systems have trouble supporting MSI and/or MSI-X interrupts. If you believe your system needs to disable this style of interrupt, the driver can be built and installed with the command:

```
# make CFLAGS_EXTRA=-DDISABLE_PCI_MSI install
```

<sup>[Source](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products/000005480.html)</sup>

Comment: What IP address and eth<x> should I type in ifconfig eth<x> <IP_address>?

Comment: This worked great for me but I had to install the kernel headers with `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` as recommended [here](https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/how-install-linux-kernel-headers-debian-or-ubuntu.html).