# Dual-boot Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04, unable to connect to wired or wireless connection, eth0 not recognized

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, drivers, ethernet

I have recently made my Intel NUC7I3BNH machine dual boot, originally with Ubuntu 16.04 and recently added Ubuntu 14.04. Everything works as expected, except that I've tried dozens of solutions but simply cannot get my wired or wireless connections to work. It sounds like it's a driver issue, because this is the output to `ifconig -a`:

```
    lo          Link encap:Local Loopback
                inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
                inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
                UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
                RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
                TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
                collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
                RX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB) TX bytes:1184 (1.1 KB)
```

I say it might be a driver issue because `eth0` doesn't appear at all, but I could be very wrong as I am somewhat inexperienced at this kind of stuff. Some other information:

- Ubuntu 16.04 runs perfectly after installation (wired and wireless connections function as expected)
- The internet connectivity issue lies within Ubuntu 14.04
- Under "Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers", the system says there are "no additional drivers available". This is true after also the "Software & Updates --> Ubuntu Software" tab recognizes there is a "Installable from CD-ROM/DVD" option because I provided the .iso file I used to install Ubuntu 14.04 in the first place.

**EDIT**

This is the output I get from `sudo lshw -C network` under 16.04:

```
*-network
    description: Intel Corporation
    product: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
    logical name: wlp58s0
    version: 78
    serial: f8:63:3f:0f:de:03
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-35-generic firmware=22.391740.0 ip=192.168.1.173 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
    resources: irq:128 memory:dc100000-dc101fff
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1f.6
    bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
    logical name: eno1
    version: 21
    serial: f4:4d:30:6b:13:dd
    capacity: 1Gbit/s
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.1-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
    resources: irq:125 memory:dc200000-dc21ffff
```

This is the output I get from `modinfo iwlwifi | head -n20` under 16.04:

```
filename:      /lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:       GPL
author:        Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:   Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:      iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-3168-26.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
```

This is the output I get from `sudo lshw -C network` under 14.04:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network Controller
    product: Intel Corporation
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
    version: 78
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:dc100000-dc101fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet controller
    product: Intel Corporation
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1f.6
    bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
    version: 21
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:dc200000-dc21ffff
```

This is the output I get from `modinfo iwlwifi | head -n20` under 14.04:

```
filename:      /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:       GPL
author:        Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <iwl@linux.intel.com>
description:   Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:      iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:      iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
```

Comment: this could be as simple as hardware supported by the kernel running under 16.04 and not under the kernel you are running under 14.04. Please boot 16.04, issue the command `sudo lshw -C network` and [edit] the output into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek I made the change. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please also include the output of  `modinfo iwlwifi | head -n20` from a 16.04 boot and the output of the same 2 commands from 14.04.  We will do our best to help you get this resolved.

Comment: As far as your wireless is concerned please [edit] the output of the following into your post: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` as well as `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` and `grep iwlwifi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` Thank you for helping us help you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Your wired networking issue:**

If you are having this issue with a fresh install of 14.04.3 it's because the Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS installation kernel doesn't support the Intel i219V gigabit controller.

Options:

A) You can build your own driver as described [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755652/ethernet-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

B) You can install a pre-built driver downloadable from [here](ftp://ftp.aslab.com/pub/linux/ubuntu-14.04.3/e1000e.ko)

Place the downloaded driver on a flash drive so that you can access it when you boot 14.04 and copy it to the appropriate location with the command:

```
sudo cp /path/to/flashdrive/e1000e.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e
```

next issue the command `sudo depmod -a`

**Note:**

```
depmod creates a list of module dependencies by reading each module under /lib/modules/version and determining what
       symbols it exports and what symbols it needs. By default, this list is written to modules.dep, and a binary hashed
       version named modules.dep.bin, in the same directory. If filenames are given on the command line, only those modules are
       examined (which is rarely useful unless all modules are listed).  depmod also creates a list of symbols provided by
       modules in the file named modules.symbols and its binary hashed version, modules.symbols.bin. Finally, depmod will output
       a file named modules.devname if modules supply special device names (devname) that should be populated in /dev on boot
       (by a utility such as udev).
```

Reboot 14.04 and confirm that the NIC is up either with the command `ifconfig` or utilizing the option on the title bar in the upper right corner of your screen as shown below:

[image: Connection info]

Now that you have verifed connectivity you can simply update your system as usual with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Note:** I do not have your hardware nor have I installed kernel 4.4.0-31-generic under 14.04 and cannot test this as both would be required. It should work as advertised on a fresh install of 14.04.3

Further useful information: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products/000005480.html

Sources:

http://faq.aslab.com/support/kb/231.html

[Ethernet not working on ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755652/ethernet-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: This did not work for me, unfortunately. I was able to download the .ko file and the first two commands worked correctly (assuming there was a typo and you meant `/path/to/flashdrive/e1000e.ko` as opposed to `/path/to/flashdrive/e1000e/ko`). However, upon reboot, it still failed to find the wired connection. I was using 14.04.5, so I even installed 14.04.3 to try it on that and it still failed.

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to the typo. I've corrected it. If you reinstalled 14.04.3  I believe the first line of your output from from modinfo iwlwifi | head -n20 under 14.04: will have changed as I 14.04.3 doesn't come default with kernel 4.4.0-31-generic, nor can I find a [current package that contains it.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=kernel-image-4&searchon=names)  If your installation ISO  does, you might benefit by [checking the hash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-17-04/503788)

Comment: You're correct in that the first line changes to `/lib/modules/3.19.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko`. Do you recommend a next step for finding a fix for this (I still have both operating systems installed and can proceed with either, as this solution unfortunately didn't work for either)? Thank you again for all of your help.

Comment: Did you try [option A)] specifically [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/755833/225694)

Comment: I can find an ethernet connection now! After the update and upgrade commands I still don't have wifi so I'll look into that further, but I can maintain a wired connection. Thank you for all of your help! The way I did it combines elements of your answer, the [option a] you had previously pointed out, and my own ideas. Should I leave another answer with my steps? I want to make sure you get credit for your help though.

Comment: @NickVandemark I'm glad you got connected. now that you are you may find that Additional drivers has an appropriate iwlwifi driver for your intel  wireless. Certainly you should provide your answer as self answering is encouraged here and others may benefit from your experience. As a rep 1 member, you do not yet have the [privilege](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) of upvoting so the only way for you to provide me with any credit is to accept my answer. Be that as it may, my main purpose is to help. The credit is nice, but mostly unnecessary. Your call.